Can you silicone the ends of a telescopic or spring shower curtain rail for a secure fit?
I’m wanting to get either a telescopic or spring shower rod however I imagine these are not very good and something would need to be done to secure them.
In this question:
How do I secure a shower curtain rod?
People have suggested a bracket which uses a dry wall anchor.  My bathroom is tiled so using anchors is not ideal.

I know I can get adhesive based holders so I imagine that would be preferable for tiles and also be strong enough?
I’m also wondering  if I simply went around the edges of the rod with silicone would that be sufficient to attach it to the tile and prevent it from falling?
If I do 2, in the event that somebody pulls the shower curtain down obviously with enough pressure it will come off, but is it more likely the rod will tear off the silicone or will the tile come off with it in which case one will find themselves re-tiling?

Thanks

They are good enough to hold a shower curtain.  Even with silicon, they will not hold up to someone grabbing them if the person slips.

I suggest you actually use one before deciding you need a solution to a problem you don't have yet.

@crip659 In your first sentence, Are you referring to using the rod without any adhesive based holder or with an adhesive based holder?  Thanks.

@JamesWilson  Without adhesive.  Unless you like to pull hard on the curtain, it should hold.

A spring-loaded curtain rod has a twist feature that can allow some adjustment to different size openings within a certain range. If you size the curtain rod for a couple inches (a few cm) bigger than the opening width then squeeze it into the smaller opening, the internal spring will exert pretty decent pressure against the walls and keep the curtain up (unless someone tries to climb the curtain).
A bit of silicone under the end pads along with this extra spring pressure from the slight oversizing of the rod may help keep the rod in place further. Once the silicone dries to the tile it will ooze into the shape of the grip grooves on the end pads and provide a matched ridge surface on the wall that may help the rod stay up under greater pulling force.

I never thought of using silicone in that manner.  It would work well on tile and be easily removable if the rod needed to be replaced.  Good answer!
